# generating java file from proto file using protocol buffer compiler - Google APIs

Tags: linux, unix, web-applications, compiler-errors, protocol-buffers

I have proto file in `C:\Sooraj\Playdrone\android-checkin-master\src\main\protobuf\checkin.proto` after unzipping protobuf the java related source code is in `C:\Sooraj\Playdrone\protobuf-2.6.1\java\src`.

When I try executing:

```
protoc -I=C:/Sooraj/Playdrone/android-checkin-master /android-checkin-master/src/main/java/com/android/checkin --java_out=C:/Sooraj/P laydrone/dest C:/Sooraj/Playdrone/android-checkin-master/android-checkin-master /src/main/protobuf/checkin.proto"
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
C:/Sooraj/Playdrone/android-checkin-master/android-checkin-master/src/main/proto buf/checkin.proto: File does not reside within any path specified using --proto_ path (or -I). You must specify a --proto_path which encompasses this file. Not e that the proto_path must be an exact prefix of the .proto file names -- protoc is too dumb to figure out when two paths (e.g. absolute and relative) are equiv alent (it's harder than you think).
```

So please help. How should I execute `protoc -I=$SRC_DIR --java_out=$DST_DIR $SRC_DIR/addressbook.proto` command with respect to my project. I have proto file and in google developers site `$SRC_DIR` meaning "where your application's source code lives"

I guess I gave every thing right. Can any one please tell how to execute protoc to generate java file from proto file?

Answer (score 0):

Your `-I` flag is this:

```
-I=C:/Sooraj/Playdrone/android-checkin-master/android-checkin-master/src/main/java/com/android/checkin
```

The purpose of `-I` is to specify where your `.proto` files are found (in order to resolve `import` statements appearing inside the files). The flag is *not* meant to specify where your Java files are located; that's what `--java_out` is for.

But your `.proto` file is this:

```
C:/Sooraj/Playdrone/android-checkin-master/android-checkin-master/src/main/protobuf/checkin.proto
```

This is not located in the directory you specified with `-I`. That's what the error is trying to tell you.

Probably, you want to change your `-I` flag to:

```
-I=C:/Sooraj/Playdrone/android-checkin-master/android-checkin-master/src/main/protobuf
```